# Adding DI to DbContext with Base implementation asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a base implementation of my DbContext as follows;

```
public abstract class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>, IDataContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
    : base(options)
    {
    }
```

where my implementation is

```
public class MyDataContext : DataContext, IMyDataContext
{
    public MyDataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options)
    : base(options)
    {

    }
```

Now when running Migrations I use the following (successfully);

```
public class MyContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDataContext>
{
    public MyContextFactory()
    {
    }

    public MyDataContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DataContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer(DbGlobals.DevDatabase);

        return new MyDataContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

however when I try to set the DbContext in my WebApi Startup.cs I add as follows;

```
        services.AddDbContext<MyDataContext>(
            options => options.UseSqlServer(DbGlobals.DevDatabase));
```

However, when I run this I get the following Error;

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[MyProject.Data.DataContext]' while attempting to activate 'MyProject.Data.EF.MyDataContext'.

I think its trying to inject the `DbContextOptions<MyDataContext>` instead of `DbContextOptions<DataContext>`. How do I resolve it so it passes in the right DbContextOptions please?

Alternatively if I adjust my MyDbContext class constructor to take `DbContextOptions<MyDataContext>` then how can I cast this down to the base implementation?

Comment: You are trying to inject some `BemfeitoDataContext` while the code that you've shown above is with a data context `MyDataContext`. Is this a typo or copy/paste mistake, or it is a real mistake?

Comment: @m3n7alsnak3 yes this was a typo from bit i have been trying

Comment: The problem is that, when you try to add the `MyDataContext` as a dbcontext it inherits `DataContext`.

You need to first inject `DataContext` and then add the dbcontext

Comment: I just found a solution based on the issue I found here  https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7533 basically  I can just use DbContextOptions for my base implementation and then DbContextOptions<T> in MyDataContext

Comment: This is what I was going to say - I'm not using the factory in my implementation. Just `MyDbContext : DbContext` as a class, and then str8 injecting it in the services (after all the other service injections). And the constructor of the class is like `public MyDbContext (DbContextOptions<MyDbContext > options)
   : base(options)
  { }`

Comment: Thanks for your help though I appreciate it :)

Comment: You are welcome. This is what this site is for :) I'm glad that you found a solution

Answer (score 0):

Based on the thread I found here

[EntityFrameworkCore Issues](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7533)

By setting the DataContext base class to be;

```
public abstract class DataContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>, IDataContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions options)
    : base(options)
    {
    }
```

and then on MyDataContext

```
public class MyDataContext : DataContext, IMyDataContext
{
    public MyDataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options): base(options)
    {

    }
```

Then the dependency injection worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using the constructor like this:

```
public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DbContext> options) : base(options) { }
```

I just used the non-generic `DbContextOptions` and my problem disappeared:

```
public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }
```